# При клике на див, менялся текст у другого блока

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Возможно ли реализовать изменение текста у одного блока, при клике на див. Блоки не имеют зависимостей друг с другом? Если это возможно, был бы благодарен увидеть реализацию. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый простой вариант:

```js
$('.block1').on('click', function() {
  $('.block2').html('Текст после изменения'); // либо .text()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block1">Кликни меня</div>
<div class="block2">Текст до изменения</div>
```

Comment: А как сделать так чтобы по повторному клику текст менялся к исходному?

Answer (score 1):

Мой вариант на нативном JavaScript, не сложнее он варианта с jQuery.

```js
document.querySelector('.block-1').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('.block-2').innerHTML = 'Новый текст!';
})
```

```html
<div class="block-1">Кликни меня!</div>
<div class="block-2">Старый текст</div>
```